# Why does a compass feel a force when placed in a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

The magnet has its own magnetic field and the same goes for the compass. So whenever I place a compass near a magnet, the magnetic field lines of both the compass and the magnet must interact to produce a new magnetic field. Then why is the compass feeling a push or pull?

It may sound like a dumb question but can you please explain why a compass experiences the force?

Comment: *the magnetic field lines of compass and magnet must interact to produce a new magnetic field* This “interaction” is merely *superposition*; they just add as vector fields.

Comment: https://www.universetoday.com/77072/how-does-a-compass-work/#:~:text=A%20compass%20works%20by%20detecting%20the%20Earth's%20natural%20magnetic%20fields.&text=This%20allows%20the%20needle%20to,are%20able%20to%20discern%20north.

Comment: @G.Smith Since the energy of the magnetic field is $B^2/\mu_0$ you can argue that the two fields interact.

Comment: This is a very deep question to which physics has no answer. Physicist know _how_ two magnets interact but do not know _why_ (electro-)magnetism exists.

Answer (score 1):

-Magnetic fields are generated by moving charges
-Magnetic fields exerts a force on moving charges

In your situation you can imagine (although it is a simplification) the moving charges
as the electrons orbiting around the nucleus in lined up orbits (lined up because it is a magnet)

So yes, the final magnetic field is generated by both the objects, but inside inside each
object it is not zero, and since inside the objet there are spinning electrons, they experience a force.
The the sum of the forces experienced by each electron is the one which makes the compass spin.

Comment: 'the electrons orbiting around the nucleus in lined up orbits (lined up because it is a magnet)'

This is incorrect.  Ferromagnetism originates from electron spin, not from electron orbital motion.

Comment: Yes you are right, but then you would need to explain magnetic dipole moment and force dependent from the gradient of the magnetic field (since you can no longer imagine a moving charge and you could not imagine why it undergoes a force). That seemed to me an overkill of the question

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understand your question, but I guess answer must be the compass is feeling a push or pull because the two magnetic fields you speak of want to align. That itself is a consequence of the effect magnets have on other moving electrons (magnets).

Comment: Can you please  provide a source for  a picture of the magnetic field lines created after the interaction of magnetic field lines of compass and magnet
That will of great help!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWUgK8W-4JM this shows the field lines, those of bar magnet are similar to compass, instead, the needle IS a magnet. I'm sure if you google there wil be much more similar results.

Comment: Why would two magnetic fields want to align? This is no answer.